# Building a widget for the first time based on data from a BLoC that was not available when InitialState was set

Tags: flutter, bloc

I'm trying to make a rather simple app, but getting stuck at the point where I have yet to be built parts of the app (regarding the widget tree) that are dependent on already calculated model data (which was not available when InitialState was set), and I can't think of a solution other than loading the new parts with some basic InitialState data if at all, and triggering a rebuild after at some point with the necessary data.

How should I handle cases like this, or what do I may overlook or miss?

What I may be wrong about are the following:
what I'm guessing, but not sure of, is that emitting a state that a not yet existing blocbuilder is listening to will throw some error, and I also think that BLoC can only build the widget tree for the first time via initial states.

EDIT:

In the end I came up with this, I have put a state trigger in the first line of the build method of the parent of the widget I was not sure of how to load (goltables wrapped with BlocBuilder), and it kinda works, although I haven't tested it thoroughly.

```
  class GamePage extends StatelessWidget {
  GamePage({super.key});
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    BlocProvider.of<GolFieldBloc>(context).add(LoadGame());
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
        title: const Center(
          child: Hero(tag: "dikk", child: Text('setup')),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(200, 200, 200, 200),
      ),
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        color: Color.fromARGB(100, 100, 100, 100),
        child: Body(),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          BlocProvider.of<GolFieldBloc>(context).add(StepInSimulation());
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.skip_next),
      ),
    );
  }
}

    class Body extends StatelessWidget {
    const Body({super.key});

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return BlocBuilder<GolFieldBloc, GolFieldState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is GameLoaded) {
            return GolTable(grid: state.grid);
          }
          if (state is GameUpdated) {
            return GolTable(grid: state.grid);
          } else {
            return Placeholder();
          }
        },
      );
    }
  }
```

Can someone explain what is happening here? I thought it will throw errors because of Body() not existing at first build.

Comment: add some code what and how you are trying to do...

Comment: one sec plsssss

Answer (score 0):

Here in that case if your model is not calculated or not receive data from Network request till that you emit one new state which will be like GolFieldState.loading() something like that once you hit the Network request or calculate your model based on the response success or failure you need to emit another state. If it's success then GolFieldState.success() and in failure case GolFieldState.error(). Let's see through one example..

bloc.dart

```
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

abstract class TextFormEvent {}

class ChangeImageOnTextForm extends TextFormEvent {}

class LoadingImageEvent extends TextFormEvent {}

abstract class ImageState {
  int get number => 0;
}

class FetchingState extends ImageState {}

class FetchedState extends ImageState {
  @override
  int number;
  FetchedState(this.number);
}

class BLocExample extends Bloc<TextFormEvent, ImageState> {
  BLocExample() : super(FetchingState()) {
    on<LoadingImageEvent>((event, emit) {
      emit(FetchingState());
    });
    on<ChangeImageOnTextForm>((event, emit) {
      emit(FetchedState(state.number));
    });
  }
}
```

home_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:practical_5/BLoc/BLoc_Example/bloc.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  TextEditingController number = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Show Image'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            BlocBuilder<BLocExample, ImageState>(
              builder: (context, state) {
                print(state);
                if (state is FetchingState) {
                  return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                } else if (state is FetchedState) {
                  print(state.number);
                  return SizedBox(
                    height: 200,
                    width: 500,
                    child: Image.network(
                      frameBuilder:
                          (context, image, frame, wasSynchronouslyLoaded) {
                        if (frame == null) {
                          return const LinearProgressIndicator();
                        } else {
                          return image;
                        }
                      },
                      'https://source.unsplash.com/random?sig=${state.number}',
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  return const LinearProgressIndicator();
                }
              },
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: BlocListener<BLocExample, ImageState>(
                listener: (context, state) {
                  if (state is FetchedState) {
                    state.number = int.parse(number.text.toString());
                  }
                },
                child: TextField(
                  controller: number,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  BlocProvider.of<BLocExample>(context)
                      .add(ChangeImageOnTextForm());
                },
                child: const Text('Change Image'))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now you can see in the example that at initial phase emit Loading state and on home scree check that if state is loading then show your appropriate UI. Once you receive the data emit new state and re-render your UI using Bloc builer.

Comment: I am still interested in what happens when state that a widget which doesn't exist yet listens to is emitted. Which I think the case is in my code, but since it's working I just don't know what's happening.

Comment: @EgyKetto Can you please send me your bloc code? So, I can look into it..